# Accessing an Objective-C ivar from outside the class at runtime

Tags: objective-c, c, objective-c-runtime

I know this idea completely breaks encapsulation, but say I have the following class extension:

```
@interface MyClass () {
    int reallyImportantIvar;
}
// ...
@end
```

Normally, the class behaves like it should inside the Objective-C layer - sending and receiving messages, etc. However there is one ('public') subroutine where I need the best possible performance and very low latency, so I would prefer to use a C method. Of course, if I do, I can no longer access *reallyImportantIvar*, which is the key to my performance-critical task.

It seems I have two options:

1. Make the instance variable a static variable instead.
2. Directly access the instance variable through the Objective-C runtime.

My question is: is Option 2 even possible, and if so, what is its overhead? (E.g. Am I still looking at an O(n) algorithm to look up a class's instance variables anyway?)

Comment: instance variable lookup is very fast.

Comment: someone else will have a better answer, but until you've proven some performance issue with a profiler, I suspect you are barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Objective-C runtime includes the `object_getInstanceVariable()` function. I believe that's what you're looking for. I haven't checked in detail, but I don't believe there is any big difference between accessing it that way and the normal way.

Comment: Since object_getInstanceVariable() takes the name of instance variable, wouldn't that be slower than giving the compiler the expression "foo->reallyImportantIvar"? Or does that expression basically compile into object_getInstanceVariable() ?

Comment: object_getInstanceVariable() is not fast. If you want fast you should use class_getInstanceVariable() and ivar_getOffset() and save that result. Or write the C function inside @implementation as described in the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, if the definition of the C function is within the `@implementation` block of the class, then it can access private ivars on that class via the usual `object->someIvar` notation. So while you *can* use the runtime to access this, I don't think you need to. Just implement the function within the `@implementation` block of the class in question, and you should be just fine.

Comment: This is little known but of great impact. Just don't go around doing it without good reason.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to declare the ivar as `@package` or `@public`. Then code outside your class's implementation that can #include that class extension can use the ivar.

`@public` allows any code to do so. `@package` limits the scope to the same binary as the class's implementation, which is usually appropriate when writing a shared library.